# How to add Image URL in ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I add `ImageView` to this list from **External URL**?

`item.put` will just add the URL link but it won't display the image at all

It's not duplicate. I just want to know what additional code I have to add to load the image on this list.

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(string);
    JSONArray offers = object.optJSONArray("data");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMap<String, String> item;
    for(int i = 0; i < offers.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = offers.getJSONObject(i);
        item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("L1", jsonChildNode.optString("gate"));
        item.put("L2", jsonChildNode.optString("stack"));
        item.put("L3", jsonChildNode.optString("image"));
        list.add(item);
    }

    sa = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
            R.layout.installs_item,
            new String[]{"L1", "L2", "L3"},
            new int[]{R.id.gate, R.id.stack, R.id.image});
    installs.setAdapter(sa);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

installs_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/L1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Head"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/L2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sub"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/L3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="desc"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How your layout looks like -> R.layout.installs_item, can you share?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: use https://github.com/bumptech/glide glide lib to load image using url

Comment: And possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460463/how-to-show-images-in-imageview-in-simple-adapter

Comment: Use CustomAdapter , i.e create your own adapter according to your need.

Comment: I have the same problem. How you add the image to the hashmap? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own adapter that contains imageview in its xml and use glide library(https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to display images in it

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended using an external lib will reduce the load and image handling process much easier.

Recommended lib: [http://square.github.io/picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

This reuses the image that already has been used and reduces data usage.

Comment: How to add it in this loop? `item.put("L3", jsonChildNode.optString("image")); String imageUrl = jsonChildNode.optString("picture"); Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView); list.add(item);`

Comment: Just add the URL as a list item (String) and while populating the get the URL and use the same code in the array adapter.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could write the code. I'm quite new to this java based android dev

Comment: 1 - Needed an array adapter (Custom array adapter) for your code replacing the SimpleAdapter.  2 - In the Adapter file you would be getting the data and replacing it with the array that you get. while doing that u need to get the URL from the Array and add it to the Picasso code.